# How to change SSIS variable values in C#

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm trying to set variables in code on an SSIS package I'm kicking off from C#.

```
Package pkg = app.LoadPackage(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SsisPkg"].ToString(), null);
pkg.Variables["User::FolderPath"].Value = Path.GetDirectoryName(e.FullPath);
pkg.Variables["User::FileName"].Value = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(e.FullPath);
```

While debugging, I inspect the values directly after setting them, but nothing has changed.  I can drill into the value (hover, navigate to it, edit value) so it doesn't *seem* to be that they aren't editable.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

**Update:**  Thanks to billinkc, I'm comfortable what I'm doing should work so long as possibly other conditions are met.  I've found that direct assignments in code fail (no error, just don't "take") and I cannot edit the values in the watch window.  I *can* edit values when I'm inspecting them.

Could the actual issue be that there's a setting flagging these as read-only?

**Answer Found:**  Needed to make the variables writable before setting the value:

```
        pkg.Variables["User::FileName"].EvaluateAsExpression = false;
```

Comment: while debugging, what's inside `Path.GetDirectoryName(e.FullPath)` and `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(e.FullPath)`. Are those the actual values?

Comment: e is a FileSystemEventArgs parameter that indeed has information about a newly created file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it right. I created a basic SSIS package. Has one Variable, FolderPath, type string. There is a single script task that fires an Information event and the contents of that expose the value of the FolderPath variable

[image]

I then created a basic C# console app like this

```
public class InformationListener : DefaultEvents
{
    public override void OnInformation(DtsObject source, int informationCode, string subComponent, string description, string helpFile, int helpContext, string idofInterfaceWithError, ref bool fireAgain)
    {
        //base.OnInformation(source, informationCode, subComponent, description, helpFile, helpContext, idofInterfaceWithError, ref fireAgain);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", subComponent, description));
    }

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sourcePackage = string.Empty;
        string path = string.Empty;
        string variableName = string.Empty;
        string designValue = string.Empty;
        string newValue = string.Empty;
        InformationListener listener = null;

        sourcePackage = @"J:\Src\SO\SSIS\Package.dtsx";
        path = @"J:\runtime";
        variableName = "User::FolderPath";
        listener = new InformationListener();

        Application app = new Application();
        Package pkg = null;
        Variable ssisVariable = null;
        pkg = app.LoadPackage(sourcePackage, null);

        ssisVariable = pkg.Variables[variableName];
        designValue = ssisVariable.Value.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Designtime value = {0}", designValue));

        ssisVariable.Value = path;

        newValue = ssisVariable.Value.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("new value = {0}", newValue));

        DTSExecResult results = DTSExecResult.Canceled;

        results = pkg.Execute(null, null, listener, null, null);

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

As you can tell from the variable inspection

[image]

and from my print statements

[image]

the design-time value of `C:\designTime` goes to `J:` because I forgot to escape my string above but we can pretend it shows `J:\runtime`.

All this said, unless we serialize the package with a call to the `SaveToXml` method, the value of User::FolderPath resets to the design time value once the object goes out of scope. Permanently updating would look like

```
app.SaveToXml(sourcePackage, pkg, null);
```

**OP EDIT** this discussion and examples led me to the answer:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dad8e218-1fe0-49db-89da-5715fb6d4b21/sql-2008-r2-ssis-c-script-task-not-setting-variable

Comment: Thanks for validating the approach is okay.  It now leaves me with why the variables are semi-read-only.  My in-code value assignments fail as do attempts to edit through the watch window, but drilling in while inspecting the variables allows me to edit.

Comment: If you create a super simple example like the above, do you still get the same result? Could it be that there is an expression assigned to the Variable or a configuration that is preventing your assignment from coming through?

Comment: Thanks again.  The discussion led me to find the answer I've added.  Don't know how many hours of beating my own head against the wall it would've taken otherwise.

Comment: Ah, so one of the variable's had EvaluateAsExpression set?

Comment: It did indeed.  What I still find really odd is I could "back-door" around it while inspecting the values, but not in the Watch window or code.  Seems to be a useful nugget in there somewhere around how to circumvent/troubleshoot issues and how VS actually works internally.  (I'll leave that to smarter people, though)